Microsoft Graph API and proxyAddresses for MSA/personal accounts
I'm working on a web application that will involve signing in with Microsoft with a personal or business account and doing various operations with their email. Sign in is working fine and we're getting the user object on the success redirect. However, I need to get more than just the stock user object, but it seems to be impossible to get anything more than the stock email using on a personal/MSA account. For example:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=proxyAddresses
This should return a user object containing only the proxyAddresses for the user, which we need. But it doesn't. Any $select query is ignored completely. It seems that this has been a problem with users for years now, and Microsoft STILL hasn't documented this limitation in the Graph API docs. I've seen older questions like this, but I'm hoping that something might have changed over the years. This web application absolutely needs to know if and what proxyAddresses the user has. It seems that any email alias in the proxyAddresses will either be an Outlook address that routes to the user's inbox or an external address. Was it always this way, and thus safe to make that assumption, or was this changed at some point and we have to take older data into account?
I can get a list of all emails on a user account in the beta with /me/profile, but Microsoft outright says not to use the beta in production, and it gives no indication as to which is the primary address. I've also found that it's not picking up new email aliases added to an account. Either that or the beta maxes out at three email addresses returned. My understanding is that MSA accounts will always have either an external email login or one of the usual Microsoft email domains, but never a custom domain managed through Microsoft as they'd have to set up the account first, then set up the domain through O365. Then again, who knows? There seem to be endless corner/legacy cases with Microsoft accounts.
At the end of the day, I'm baffled that Microsoft doesn't provide this functionality and I'm hoping that there's some kind of workaround here that doesn't involve using their potentially brittle beta. I even asked Copilot, hoping that it would at least know enough about Microsoft's own APIs and services to get it right, but it keeps giving me bad information.
